# Classic ASP error Variable not Defined

Tags: xml, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to execute below provided For Each Next loop under classic ASP code.

```vb
For Each node in xml.SelectSingleNode("/Root/Div").ChildNodes
 response.write node.SelectSingleNode("item").text
Next
```

But I am Receiving error as

> Variable Not Defined 'node', 800a01f4

XML I want to process is as like below

```
<Root>
  <div>
   <div><item>I1</item></div>
   <div><item>I2</item></div>
   <div><item>I3</item></div>
   <div><item>I4</item></div>
  </div>
</Root>
```

Comment: I have to ask, why don't you define the variable?

Comment: What is the structure of the XML? The likely cause is the node `/Root/Div` doesn't exist or has no child nodes.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it that wouldn't happen for that particular error. It's likely complaining at the `For Each node` part which means you probably have `Option Explicit` set which requires all variables to be declared as @MCND [points out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737831/classic-asp-error-variable-not-defined#comment74519110_43737831) in the comments. To correct it add a declaration `Dim node`.

Comment: I Tried to add declaration as 'Dim node' but after executing this change it thrown error Object Required: 'node.selectSingleNode(..)'

Comment: @Audumbar the [most recent edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43737831/3) shows that you should be looking for `/Root/div` not `/Root/Div`, if the XML structure is correct. The case is important in XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track just came unstuck on some of the errors [we discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737831/classic-asp-error-variable-not-defined/43762663#comment74545142_43737831) in the comments.

[After realising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737831/classic-asp-error-variable-not-defined/43754131#comment74530903_43737831) that `Option Explicit` was set somewhere in your code that wasn't shown, the fix was to add

```vb
Dim node
```

The next error was a simple fix and a very common error.

> Object Required: 'node.selectSingleNode(..)

The `node` object wasn't an object because the `xml.SelectSingleNode("/Root/Div").ChildNodes` call never returned one. This happens because the XPath string was incorrect and needed to follow the XML structure exactly, along with any case defined in the elements.

Below is an example based on your code but with some interpretation just to make the sample work, but I suspect just changing the XPath from

```
/Root/Div
```

to

```
/Root/div
```

would fix the problem.

```vb
<%
Option Explicit

Dim xml_data : xml_data = Join( _
  Array( _
    "<Root>" _
    , "<div>" _
    ,   "<div><item>I2</item></div>" _
    ,   "<div><item>I1</item></div>" _
    ,   "<div><item>I3</item></div>" _
    ,   "<div><item>I4</item></div>" _
    ,  "</div>" _
    , "</Root>") _
  )

Dim xml : Set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
Dim node

Call xml.LoadXML(xml_data)

For Each node In xml.SelectSingleNode("/Root/div").ChildNodes
  Call Response.Write(node.SelectSingleNode("item").Text & "<br />")
Next
%>
```

Output:

```
I2
I1
I3
I4
```

Answer (score 0):

Work through this:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim sXML : sXML = Join(Array( _
    "<Root>" _
   , "<div>" _
   ,   "<div><item>I2</item></div>" _
   ,   "<div><item>I1</item></div>" _
   ,   "<div><item>I3</item></div>" _
   ,   "<div><item>I4</item></div>" _
   ,  "</div>" _
   , "</Root>"))
Dim oXML : Set oXML = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDOCUMENT")
oXML.loadXML sXML
Dim oNode ' Uncomment to get: Variable ist nicht definiert: 'oNode'
' try "/Root/Div" or "/Root/Div/div" or "/Root/div" to realize why those are
' bad XPath expressions given your "/Root/div/div/item" structure
For Each oNode In oXML.SelectNodes("/Root/div/div")
    WScript.Echo oNode.tagName, oNode.firstChild.tagName, oNode.firstChild.text
Next
' For Each iterates over a collection; .SelectSingleNode returns
' a single node (surprise, surprise)
```

Output:

```
cscript 43737831.vbs
div item I2
div item I1
div item I3
div item I4
```

to learn which of your blunders causes which of your problems.

Comment: The [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43754131/2) I made added the correct syntax highlighting for [tag:vbscript] and removed unnecessary highlighting from the output by adding `<!-- language: lang-none -->`, so why roll it back? Also on the *"thru"* edit see this - [Thru vs. Through—Which Is Right?](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/through-thru/)

Comment: `Variable ist nicht definiert` is quite clearly German, as [so] requires [questions, answers and comments in English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/692942) I thought I'd edit it to be `Variable Not Defined`, but as you [rolled it back](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43754131/6) guess not.